# How to html decode a string in Elixir?

Tags: html, string, elixir, decode

Here's a string I'm trying to decode.

```
"Ren &amp; Stimpy The Lost Episodes Disc.1 [MP4-AAC] 480p DVD"
```

I'd like to end up with a string like:

```
"Ren & Stimpy The Lost Episodes Disc.1 [MP4-AAC] 480p DVD"
```

---

I've tried using the [URI.decode](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/URI.html#decode/1) function but it doesn't work, I get the same `&amp;` symbol.

```
iex(1)> URI.decode "Ren &amp; Stimpy The Lost Episodes Disc.1 [MP4-AAC] 480p DVD"
"Ren &amp; Stimpy The Lost Episodes Disc.1 [MP4-AAC] 480p DVD"
```

Comment: https://github.com/martinsvalin/html_entities

Answer (score 6):

Add the [html_entities](https://hex.pm/packages/html_entities) package from Hex.pm

```
defp deps do
  [{:html_entities, "~> 0.5.2"}]
end
```

Then just pass it your string:

```
iex> HtmlEntities.decode("Ren &amp; Stimpy The Lost Episodes Disc.1 [MP4-AAC] 480p DVD")
"Ren & Stimpy The Lost Episodes Disc.1 [MP4-AAC] 480p DVD"
```